# Is "My schedule got freed up" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

I want to express the idea that due to the cancellation of some event, my schedule changed and I have more time for something else.

Here are some candidates I thought of.

- My schedule freed up.
- My schedule got freed up.
- My schedule was freed up.

Which one would work best?

I know of the usage of "I freed up some time", or "I freed up my schedule", but I would like to insist on the idea that the changes to my schedule were not because of me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "My schedule is now free" suggests that you were not previously available.

Comment: "My schedule has been freed up by the cancellation of XXX" or "My schedule has opened up"

Comment: @PeterJennings Yes. I much prefer "opened up" - and it is more literate too, since the verb "to free" is transitive. So nothing can simply "free", in the way it can "open" or "close". And "free-up" is a colloquialism anyway. But in Britain we don't have "schedules" - at least not in that sense, do we. We are apt to speak about our "timetable".

Comment: @WS2 Some in the UK might say "My diary has opened up" although in my experience "schedule" is fairly common.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! "opened up" does sound better that "got freed up" which is the one I wanted to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it,

> My schedule got freed up

is the one you want. Use of the passive voice implies that the freeing of the schedule was not done by you.

Comment: What is a "freed up"? This is truly horrible. Is it vernacular?